# How to loop array imageURL in JSON for show in image view

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have function for loop data(title, price, drug) JSON But I can't loop imageUrl to show in imageview on this function please help see my code.

This function barcodeReaded

```
func barcodeReaded(barcode: String) {
    print("Barcode is: \(barcode)")
    showCodeLabel.text = barcode

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: episode.thumbnailURL!)
    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
    self.thumbnailImageView.image = image

    let episodes = Episode.downloadAllEpisodes()
    var filteredEpisodes = episodes.filter({ $0.testCode == barcode })
    if filteredEpisodes.count > 0 {

        titleLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].title
        drugLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].drug
        priceLabel.text = filteredEpisodes[0].price
        //thumbnailImageView.image = filteredEpisodes[0].thumnailURL

        }
}
```

This JSON file

```
{
    "episode": [

         {
          "testCode": "11111111",
          "title": "Stomachic  mixture 180 ml",
          "drug": "AAAAA",
          "thumbnailURL": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/rxscan-a14ee.appspot.com/o/j01.jpg?alt=media&token=5718797b-fc9c-416e-9394-b544c2880dc9",
          "price": "100"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "22222222",
          "title": "Parasetamol   200 ml",
          "drug": "BBBBB",
          "thumbnailURL": "urlImage",
          "price": "150"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "33333333",
          "title": "Beramol 300 ml",
          "drug": "CCCCC",
          "thumbnailURL": "urlImage",
          "price": "120"
        }

    ] 

}
```

This some code

```
import Foundation

class Episode
{
    var title: String?
    var thumbnailURL: NSURL?
    var drug: String?
    var price: String?
    var testCode: String?

    init(title: String, thumbnailURL: NSURL, drug: String, price: String, testCode: String)
{
    self.title = title
    self.thumbnailURL = thumbnailURL
    self.drug = drug
    self.price = price
    self.testCode = testCode
}

typealias EpisodeDictionary = [String : AnyObject]

init(espDictionary: EpisodeDictionary)
{
    self.title = espDictionary["title"] as? String
    self.thumbnailURL = NSURL(string: espDictionary["thumbnailURL"] as! String)
    self.drug = espDictionary["drug"] as? String
    self.price = espDictionary["price"] as? String
    self.testCode = espDictionary["testCode"] as? String
}

static func downloadAllEpisodes() -> [Episode]
{
    var episodes = [Episode]()

    let jsonFile = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("testJson3edit6", ofType: "json")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: jsonFile!)
    if let jsonDictionary = NetworkService.parseJSONFromData(jsonData) {
        let espDictionaries = jsonDictionary["episodes"] as! [EpisodeDictionary]
        for dict in espDictionaries {
            let episode = Episode(espDictionary: dict)
            episodes.append(episode)
        }
    }

    return episodes
  } 
 }
```

NetworkService.swift

```
import Foundation

class NetworkService
{
    // TODO: Make this class be able to download images from a URL
    lazy var configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    lazy var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: self.configuration)

    let url: NSURL

    init(url: NSURL)
    {
        self.url = url
    }

    func downloadImage(completion: (NSData -> Void))
    {
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self.url)
        let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in

            if error == nil {
                if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                    switch (httpResponse.statusCode) {
                    case 200:
                        if let data = data {
                            completion(data)
                        }

                    default:
                        print(httpResponse.statusCode)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error download data: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        dataTask.resume()
    }
}

extension NetworkService
{
    static func parseJSONFromData(jsonData: NSData?) -> [String : AnyObject]?
    {
        if let data = jsonData {
            do {
                let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String : AnyObject]
                return jsonDictionary
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Error processing json data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

This code for get image that use in detailViewController Which I don't know how to apply with function barcodeReaded.

```
if episode.thumbnailURL != nil {

            if let thumbnailURL = episode.thumbnailURL {
                let networkService = NetworkService(url: thumbnailURL)
                networkService.downloadImage({ (data) in
            //thumbnailImageView.image = episode.thumbnailURL
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.thumbnailImageView.image = image
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically with `thumbnailImageView.image = episode.thumbnailURL` your are trying to assign a `String` to an object of type `UIImage`.

You should do it:

**1. Get `NSURL` from your json string**

```
let url = NSURL(string: episode.thumbnailURL)!
```

**2. Get the `NSData` of that `NSURL`**

```
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)!
```

**3. Assign the `UIImage` from `NSData`**

```
let image = UIImage(data: data)
self.thumbnailImageView.image = image
```

Comment: Sorry I'm starter When I add code in function barcodeReaded got error cannot convert NSURL to String on First line  your code.

Comment: @Kopiko in `barcodeReaded` replace your comment with this code.

Comment: let url = NSURL(string: episode.thumbnailURL)!  this line got error.

Comment: @Kopiko compile time or runtime?

Comment: can not convert value of type 'NSURL?' to expected argument type 'String'

Comment: @Kopiko check if episode.thumbnailURL is a string or nsurl..if nsurl you can avoid the let url.....

Comment: @Kopiko ok so you can skip first point and go through the others.

Comment: please see my edited post on function barcodeReaded. I'm not sure this true When I scan barcode breakpoint page has shown.

Comment: and show green arrow on this line > let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: episode.thumbnailURL!)